# JSF 2 - Significance of ResponseWriter.flush()

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, flush

I was doing some testing and i realized that the writer doesn't get automatically flushed i.e i dont see any response on the client side until all the components have been rendered?

I also tried manually flushing the response writer but it didn't make any difference. Is there a way to allow manual flushes so that the response becomes available to the client earlier?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you used the wrong writer or called flush at the wrong moment or misinterpreted the results (i.e. behaviour is browser/CSS/JS specific). The following test case works for me with Mojarra 2.1.3.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
```

with

```
public String getText() throws Exception {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().responseFlushBuffer();
    Thread.sleep(250);
    return "<br />a line of text";
}
```

You see them in browser clearly appearing line by line instead of all at once.

Please note that the above approach is not really recommended. You can finetune the response buffer size with the context param `javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE`.

```
<context-param>
    <!-- Flush every 128 bytes (default is 1024) -->
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>128</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: you're right. i was using a simple context.getResponseWriter().flush(). The method you cited was the correct way to go.

Comment: i still have another related question. how does the BUFFER_SIZE matter, because irrespective of whatever the buffer size, the responseFlushBuffer() method is going to clear out the response

Comment: When the buffer is full, then it will be automatically flushed. So if the size is (much) less than default, it will be (much) more often automatically flushed.

Comment: i see. i'll do some testing and see if that automatic flush is working. but if the default size is really 1024, then i should have seen a flush happening in my earlier tests while viewing the response in firebug. But i'll confirm.. thx